# ¿Como llamar un fragment desde un case switch?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy trabajando con `fragment` y con la sentencia `switch`, como puedo llamar un `fragment` en ves de un Activity desde un `case 0:` ya que tengo ahí el método para poder ver los detalles de un producto.

**Sentencia Switch**

```
@Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

                    switch (i){
                        case 0:
                        //En vez de un Activity quiero llamar un fragment aqui
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContex(),DetallesActivity.class).putExtra("position",position));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            break;
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues, lo puedes hacer así:

```
                switch (i){
                    case 0:
                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                        ft.add(R.id.contenedor, new TuFragmento());
                        ft.commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Este es un ejemplo, en donde `container` es el id del `FrameLayout` en donde se realizara la transacción  (reemplazo de Fragmentos).

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

    switch (number) {
      case 0:
           fragment = new FragmentA();
           break;
      case 1:
           fragment = new FragmentB();
           break;
      case 2:
           fragment = new FragmentC();
           break;
      }

      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
      .commit();

   }
```